# How to update data to MongoDB from registration page using React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-hooks

I am creating a sign up form component for a web application using React and Redux. It renders correctly however when I clicked on the submit button, the data(name,e-mail,password) did not register in MongoDB. If I user Postman to post to the localhost server, it works fine.

Initially, I used the class component but I changed it to a functional component in order to use @material-ui and hooks.

```
   import React, { useState } from "react";
   import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
   import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
   import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
   import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
   import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
  import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
  import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
  import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
   import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
   import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
   import Logo from "./assets/images/logo_transparent.png";

 //redux
 import { connect } from "react-redux";
  //proptypes
 import PropTypes from "prop-types";
  import { register } from "./actions/authActions";


 const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
   "@global": {   
  // insert style inside here 
 }));

 function SignUp() {
 const classes = useStyles();
  const [form, setValues] = useState({
name: "",
email: "",
password: "",
msg: null
 });

const propTypes = {
isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
error: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
 };

 const onChange = e => {
setValues({
  ...form,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
  };

const onSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
const { name, email, password } = setValues();

//create user object
const newUser = {
  name,
  email,
  password
};
//attempt to register
propTypes.register(newUser);
  };

  return (
<Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
  <CssBaseline />

  <div className={classes.paper}>
    <Avatar
      alt="logo"
      src={Logo}
      style={{
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      }}
    />
    <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            autoComplete="fname"
            name="fullName"
            variant="outlined"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="fullName"
            label="Full Name"
            autoFocus
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            value={form.email}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            value={form.password}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} />
      </Grid>
      <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.submit}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        Sign Up
      </Button>

      <Button
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.home}
      >
        Home
      </Button>
      <br />
      <br />

      <Grid container justify="flex-end">
        <Grid item>
          <Link href="http://localhost:3000/" variant="body2">
            Already have an account? Sign in
          </Link>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  </div>
  <Box mt={5}>
  </Box>
</Container>
  );
 }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  error: state.error //getting from reducer
   });

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 { register } //from redux actions //mapdispatchtoprop
)(SignUp); //component
```

//authActions.js

```
  import axios from "axios";
 import { returnErrors } from "./errorActions";

  import {
  USER_LOADING,
    USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL
  } from "./types";

  //check token and load user
  export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
//User loading
dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });

  axios
.get("/api/auth/user", tokenConfig(getState))
.then(res =>
  dispatch({
    type: USER_LOADED,
    payload: res.data
    })
   )
.catch(err => {
  dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
  dispatch({
    type: AUTH_ERROR
    });
   });
  };

//register user
 export const register = ({ name, email, password }) => dispatch => 
  {
//headers
const config = {
  headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
   };

 //request body
const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

 axios
  .post("api/users", body, config)
.then(res =>
  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    payload: res.data
  })
  )
 .catch(err => {
  dispatch(
    returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 
    "REGISTER_FAIL")
  );
  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_FAIL
  });
});
   };

 //setup config/headers and token
  export const tokenConfig = getState => {
 //get token from localstorage
 const token = getState().auth.token;

  //headers
   const config = {
  headers: {
  "Content-type": "application/json"
   }
   };

  //if token, add to headers
  if (token) {
   config.headers["x-auth-token"] = token;
   }
   return config;
    };
```

store.js

```
 import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
 import thunk from "redux-thunk";
 import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = {};

 const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
 rootReducer,
initialState,
compose(
applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__
  ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  : f => f
  )
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, just wrote you an answer, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're pretty close, but you're taking the action-creator from `propTypes`, which seems off.

```
//attempt to register
propTypes.register(newUser);
  };
```

Declare your `SignUp` component with the `props` argument

```
function SignUp(props){
```

Then you need to get the action-creator from `props`, not invoke it from `propTypes`

```
const onSubmit = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const { name, email, password } = form;

  //create user object
   const newUser = {
      name,
      email,
      password
    };

   //attempt to register
    props.register(newUser)
};
```

Comment: What happens to the propTypes then since it was assigned but never been used? Still didn't work as the token was not created.

Comment: @DanialAsrafNorbee propTypes isnt something that gets explicitly called, you use it to create type-structure for your component-props. Hmm can you confirm what action gets executed? Like do you see your reducer update at all?

Comment: If I click the submit button without entering any fields, the REGISTER_FAIL action should be visible in the redux devtool chrome extension but apparently it doesn't. The error message also says that no store is found. I have edited the question to include the store.js so that you can check whether the configurations are correct.